# errors in figure caption in r markdown caption outside float

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, figure

I tried to put the plot objects in r markdown. The `fig.cap` worked well in the first r chunk. However problems occurred when I tried to put the second figure. Please see the code below.

The YAML looks like this

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: no
header-includes:
- \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{multicol}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{caption}
```

The code in r chunk is

```
{r trend_1, echo=F, fig.cap='The air pollution trend of different groups',out.width='50%',message=F, fig.show='hold'}
```

The code for plotting is (these are two plot objects)

```
state.con.oz
state.con.pm
```

I got an error `! Package caption Error: \caption outside float.` Any ideas?

BTW, I wonder how to create a figure footnote in r markdown?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a MWE with YAML header etc.? BTW: have a look at `bookdown` for footnotes, cross-referencing etc.

Comment: @J_F I just added the YAML header. Unfortunately, I did not find any information regarding footnotes in `bookdown`.

Comment: @J_F Add table footnote is handy with `threeparttable::footnote`. However, figure note is complicated.

Comment: Try to name your R code chunk without underlines ... works for me.

Comment: @J_F Works for me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to name your R code chunk without underlines

````
```{r trend1, echo=F, fig.cap='The air pollution trend of different groups',out.width='50%',message=F, fig.show='hold'}

your_plot
```
````